# azure how to move resource group from azure ad tenant/subscription to new B2C tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We have azure iot solution with 3 resource groups and lot of various services/resources created under these groups. Currently we are using default Azure AD for users and authentication. Now we have to move all these resource to azure B2C AD under the same subscription.
I have created B2C AD but not getting info how to move all these to this new AD tenant. Any pointers.

Thanks,
Bhaskar

Comment: As of now, I guess B2C doesn't support this. It doesn't allow you to move the resources. Keep all the resources in the main AD Tenant and use B2C for Authentication purpose.

Comment: Hi, I yet to try this but as Ramakrishna mentioned it looks it it is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the tenant of the subscription which your resources located, but 
 when you associate a subscription to a different directory, users that have roles assigned using role-based access control (RBAC) will lose their access.

All of your users have a single home directory for authentication, if you want to give the permissions to the users in the old tenant, you need to invite them as guest to the new tenant, then add them to the subscription again.

For more details, see [Associate or add an Azure subscription to your Azure Active Directory tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory).

[image]

Besides, changing the tenant will not transferring billing ownership, more details about that, see [Transfer ownership of an Azure subscription to another account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-subscription-transfer).